# Law of total expectation and state space partition

Tags: expected-value, set-partition

Let's say we have 3 binary independent random variables $X_k$, e.g. each one represents if an event happens or not. he possible values of a $k$-th variable are $0$ and $m_k$. Then, if I am not mistaken, the state space is given by

$$
\Omega = \{123, 12\overline{3}\, 1\overline{2}3\, \overline{1}23, 1\overline{23}, \overline{1}2\overline{3}, \overline{12}3, \overline{123} \}
$$

where $\overline{k}$ denotes event $k$ not happening.

Define $Y = X_1+X_2+X_3$. By the law of total expectation, if I am not mistaken,

$$
E[Y] = \sum E\left[Y|\omega_i\right]P(\omega_i) 
\\= (m_1+m_2+m_3)P(123) + (m_1+m_2)P(12\overline{3})+(m_1+m_3)P(1\overline{2}3) + m_1P(1\overline{23}) + ...
\\= m_1 \left( P(123) + P(12\overline{3}) + P(1\overline{2}3) + P(1\overline{23}) \right) + ...
\\= m_1 \left( P(12) + P(1\overline{2}) \right) + ...
\\= m_1P(1) + m_2P(2) + m_3P(3)
$$

where in the intermediate steps above I am only showing the terms involving $m_1$ for readability.  The results is of course nothing more than a rule for the expectation of a sum of RVs, but how do I interpret it terms of the partition of the original sample space $\Omega$ and the law of total expectation?

Comment: I don't really understand what you are asking.  The first expression gives the value in terms of the state space partition.  By arithmetic manipulation, you've shown it's equal to the value given by linearity of expectation.  What is missing?

Comment: @saulspatz  Thank you for your comment.  I am wondering if the final expression can also be seen as an application of the law of total expectation with sample space $\{1, 2, 3\}$? And if yes, then how is this reduction in sample space occurs?

Comment: @saulspatz  Right, but is this collection, $\{1, 2, 3\}$ a partition of the state space? Because, if I am not mistaken, for the law of total probability that was the set has to be, no?

Comment: To apply the law of total expectation, we partition the event space, which I take it is what you mean by the state space, not the sample space.  The sample space is the range of values that a random variable can attain.  Each of your $X_k$ has sample space $\{0,1\}$.  Again, what you've done seems perfect to me, and I can't see what more there is to this.